# PHP: rename() fails silently but returns true

Tags: php, rename

I have a script which is executed on a server.
This script renames a file to move it to a nested directory.

The script resides in:
/var/www/vhosts/XXXXX/httpdocs/XXXXX/import_export/orders

The file should be moved and renamed to:
/var/www/vhosts/XXXXX/httpdocs/XXXXX/import_export/orders/backup

Permissions on the backup directory are 755

Here is my code:

```
$now = time();
$dateString = date('d-m-Y', $now);
$newFileName = '/var/www/vhosts/XXXXX/httpdocs/XXXXX/import_export/orders/backup/orders-' . $dateString . '.csv';
$result = rename('orders.csv', $newFileName);
var_dump($result);
```

This code returns true, but the file still exists in the source folder and has not been moved to the backup folder.

If I execute the script on my localhost, renaming and moving works just fine.

What is wrong?

Comment: note: the `$now` business is pointless. `date()` defaults to using "now" if you don't provide a time value.

Comment: have you tried with specifying the full path for orders.csv ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: When you ask a question about an error, ***ALWAYS***, post the error log. To enable error reporting to your php code append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script, what does it return ?

Comment: Are you owner of the sever? and is you have permission to move file by running code. I think its permission problem.

Comment: *Permissions on the backup directory are 755* ... so no-one but the owner has permission to write to that directory? Did you create it with FTP? If so, the FTP user will be the owner and **not** the Apache/PHP user.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try providing the full path in both arguments, e.g.

```
$basePath = '/var/www/vhosts/XXXXX/httpdocs/XXXXX/import_export/orders';
$currentFileName = $basePath . '/order.csv';
$newFileName = $basePath . '/backup/orders-' . $dateString . '.csv';
$result = rename($currentFileName, $newFileName);
```

Comment: It's best to include a code example or deeper explanation of how you think the problem could be solved. Otherwise your answer will likely get flagged as low quality.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to do some safety checks beforehand as below with `file_exists()` and `is_writable()`. You could also show the error with the [`error_get_last()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php) if `rename()` returns false as follows:

```
if (!rename('orders.csv', $newFilename)) {
  $error = error_get_last();
  // TODO: DO something with $error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> PHP: rename() fails silently but returns true

Set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` in order to debug your script properly, i.e.:

```
<?php
//comment on production mode
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
// the rest of the code...
```

---

Your `rename` block seems to lack the **fullpath** of the original file, also, the `date` block is **redundant**. You may want to check if the destination dir `is _writable()` before using `rename()`, here's what I'd do:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set( "Europe/Lisbon" ); // Set the default timezone to avoid warnings
$dateString = date('d-m-Y'); // no neeed for $now here, it's redundant
$destDir = "/var/www/vhosts/XXXXX/httpdocs/XXXXX/import_export/orders/backup/";
$destFn = "orders-{$dateString}.csv";
if(is_writable($destDir)){ //check if the destination dir is writable
   $result = rename('/full/path/to/orders.csv', $destDir.$destFn); // we need to set the full path of "orders.csv"
   var_dump($result);
}else{
    echo "destination dir not writable";
}
```